# Dynamically Add & Remove HTML Form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a one form to add link of any site. After submit it will store in DB.

Problem:- 
When i click on add form button it will add one new form to add link of site. if user want to enter 5 site link then he will click 5 times on add form button and so on.but when user submit form then i validate the links and if it is invalid then it will throw the error message.

When i am adding form i am also adding remove button. Before submit form it will work fine but after submit form the remove button not working.

Code:-

```
function addLinkFrom() 
{
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'linkform';
div.innerHTML = '<label class="linklabel">Add Link: </label><input type="text" id="txtaddlink" name="txtaddlink[]" class="expfield" placeholder="Enter Link"/>\
    <div class="clearboth"></div>\
    <input type="button" class="btn linkpad btn-primary" value="Remove" onclick="removeLinkForm(this)">\
    <div class="line"></div>';
    document.getElementById('addlinkform').appendChild(div);
}

function removeLinkForm(input) 
{
document.getElementById('addlinkform').removeChild( input.parentNode );
}
```

so if you have any idea to solve this please share it with me.

Comment: could you post the relevant html code as well?

Comment: Add Form Link:-<a onClick="return addLinkFrom();">Add Link</a>          and other all code is dynamic.i mean jast fetching data from MySQL and display it in the form.

Comment: Does `input.parentNode` actually resolve to a child of _#addlinkform_ after the _HTML_ is rendered? What is your error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error.i also check this button through firebug.it will show the remove function onclick of button.but when i am click on this the form will not hide or vanish.